# Configuring max iterations in metaMDS

Tags: r, vegan

I´m trying ro reduce the iterations of metaMDS (vegan library) to 1, but it does not work. Here I add an example code

Please help

```
library(vegan)
metaMDS(dune, trymax = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give both `trymax` and `try`. There is a reason to make this difficult, but try:

```r
metaMDS(dune, trymax=1, try=1)
```

The documentation says that `try` and `trymax` are the minimum and maximum numbers of random starts, and both default to 20. Both must be at the same value to force a fixed number. If you only have `trymax=1`, the minimum will still default to `try=20` unless you change it.

Currently the logic is to work `try` times and first then check if `trymax` was reached. I could change it, naturally, but I'm not sure it is good not to try hard enough. You seem to suppose an opposite strategy. It seems that I did this in 2016, and then this sounded like a good idea. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: FWIW, the next **vegan** release will change this policy, and `trymax` will give the maximum number of tries, even when the minimum number (`try`) is higher. That would be either version 2.6-1 (I hope so) or 2.5-8 (I hope not). The github version (2.6-0) already works like this.